# Return a value while hiding output from logs

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, remix

I would like to return a value to one ethereum address without the other parties of the contract seeing the returned value. The returned values always show up in the logs as decoded output. How do I pass a value to only one entity without the others in the contract knowing it? Is there a way to hide the decoded output from the logs? if there any other way?

Comment: Ethereum is a public blockchain. You might want to use any other blockchain, eg hyperledger, or the concept of zksnarks would seem interesting to you.

Comment: @Ayushya what is zksnarks?

Comment: It depends on the source of the information. 

It's especially difficult to keep a secret on a system that's optimized for transparency. Some use-cases can be solved with obfuscation or stealth. For example, if your value can be derived on a read-only basis it could be done without informing the rest of the network. Maybe shed a little more light on what you need to accomplish and someone will know if it's feasible.

Comment: @RobHitchens it is just a read only basis ..  a key that I want to be read by one entity without the other knowing it. can you tell me how it can be done?

Comment: Yes, do. It may help to update the question. Even just add "Update" headline and keep going.